# Что такое "общих ответов от своего имени"?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Русский:

> бронзовый знак: Заработать не менее 100 баллов репутации за минимум 20 *общих ответов от своего имени* на вопросы с меткой javascript

Английский:

> gold badge: Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 *non-community wiki answers* in the .net tag

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

Мне кажется, идёт речь не о баллах рейтинга, а о количестве плюсов (которое в 10 раз меньше). Плюс форма с императивом смотрится нелепо в тултипе.

Поэтому предлагаю такой вариант:

> **Нужно заработать** не менее $score$ **голосов** за **как** минимум $answerScoreStr$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой «$tagLink$».

Для варианта на странице знака (убрал повторение слова «получение/получить»):

> Для получения этого знака вам необходимо заработать не менее $threshold$ голосов за как минимум $atLeast$ ответов, не отмеченных как общие.

Comment: В принципе согласен, но слово "нужно" я бы убрал.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Без него тултип смотрится странно. «бронзовый знак: Заработать не менее...». Что, простите? (ц)

Comment: А по-моему, наоборот, с ним странно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Возможно, с «нужно» тоже не идеал. А как лучше?

Comment: Бронзовый знак: Нужно заработать... Кому нужно, чего нужно? У меня уже есть знак и всё ещё что-то нужно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тогда напишите альтернативный ответ?

Comment: Я уже написал, ещё пару мест попутно поменяв ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Окей, тогда в случае, если знак реально уже заработан, надо писать «Бронзовый знак: вы заработали ...» (если это мой знак) и «Участник Х заработал ...».

Comment: @Qwertiy: А если _не_ заработан, то «бронзовый знак: для него вам нужно заработать...». А если не в вашем профиле, то «бронзовый знак: для его получения нужно заработать...»

Comment: Какая-то сложная схема получается. Мне вполне нравится как есть - просто "заработать".

Comment: @Qwertiy: на мой вкус, нипаруски как-то.

Comment: Голосов- неверно. Должен быть рейтинг.

Comment: Два голоса против, три голоса за. В сумме пять голосов, но 1 рейтинга.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Хм. Я под рейтингом понял бы скорее не голоса, а баллы. Думаю, остальные тоже.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Проблема в том, что понятия «рейтинг» юзеры не знают, и поэтому будут привязывать его к знакомым им понятиям. То есть к репутации. Я не знаю как лучше сказать, честно

Answer (score 4):

Нынешняя фраза пытается выдать все подробности на одном дыхании. Предлагаю сообщать информацию по частям, чтобы её было легче усвоить.

> Дать не менее $answerScoreStr$ ответов на вопросы с меткой «$tagLink$» и заработать не менее $score$ баллов рейтинга. Общие ответы не учитываются.

И хорошо бы заключить тэг в кавычки. Есть вариант кавычек, которые осилят Транзифекс и всплывающая подсказка?

Comment: Хороший вариант, кстати. (И да, кавычки умеют все, Unicode кругом.)

Comment: Всё-таки рейтинг это не совсем голоса. А разделение предложений мне нравится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Исправил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Что нужно сделать, чтобы задействовать новый вариант перевода?

Answer (score 3):

Это ошибка. Пока что я внес изменения, которые удовлетворительно исправляют проблему перевода. Если вы хотите сделать перевод ещё лучше - предлагайте варианты.

В [транзифексе это строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english?q=Earn%20at%20least%20%24score%24):

> 6690, 6691, 6692  (one, few, many):
>   Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag

У них есть расширенный вариант:

> 6687, 6688, 6689 (one, few, many):
>   Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag. These users can single-handedly mark $tagLink$ questions as duplicates

Должно быть примерно так (изменения выделил полужирным):

> **Заработать** не менее $score$ баллов **рейтинга** за минимум $answerScoreStr$ **ответов, не отмеченных как общие,** на вопросы с меткой $tagLink$.

На [странице тематического знака](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) есть ещё такая строка:

> ([Tx:2235](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263930?q=You%20must%20have%20a%20total%20score))  You must have a total score of $threshold$ in at least $atLeast$ non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

**Было:**

> Для получения этого знака, вам необходимо иметь как минимум 1000 баллов репутации в как минимум 200 вопросах, не отмеченных как общие.

**Исправил его на:**

> Для получения этого знака вам необходимо **заработать** $threshold$ баллов **рейтинга за не менее чем** $atLeast$ **ответов**, не отмеченных как общие.

Думаю, очевидно, что если знак дается за 100 баллов, то за 101 его не заберут.

Comment: формулировка странная. учитываются только не-общие ответы. ну и к тому же, разве можно отвечать не от своего имени?

Comment: @PashaPash: можно тогда буквально написать, "не-общих ответов".

Comment: Вообще-то я из уже полученного знака тултип копировал. Тут даже текст не тот.

Comment: @Qwertiy: это вы про ссылку на страницу знака? Там в правой части страницы есть дополнительные описания.

Comment: Добавил скриншот в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy: похоже, одни и те же строки используются как во всплывающих подсказках, так и на странице знака.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю ещё такой вариант:

> Заработать не менее $score$ голосов за $answerScoreStr$ или более именных ответов на вопросы с меткой «$tagLink$».